# How To Auto Load div content in PHP codeigniter?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I have view `\views\ngoding\AutoLoad.php` :

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
setInterval(function(){
$("#content").load('data.php')
}, 5000);
});
</script>

<style>
#content{
background-color: #00A1E0;
font-size: 24px;
font-weight: bold;
padding-top : 10px;
color : #fff;
min-height: 200px;
}
#content,h1 {
    text-align: center;
}
</style>

<title>Auto Load Page in Div using Jquery</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Auto Load Page in Div</h1>
    <div id="content">Please wait....</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have code after load 5 second  `views\ngoding\load.php`  :

```
<?php 

$err = file_get_contents("application\logs\log.php");
echo preg_replace(array('/(^|\R)ERROR\s*-\s*/', '/(^|\R)(.*?)\s*-->\s*/'), array('$1', '$1$2 '), $err);
echo "<br>";
echo "Content akan load selama 5 detik";

for ($i = 0; $i <=10; $i++) {
    echo $i. "<br/>";
}

?>
```

I have Controller `controllers\AutoLoadDiv.php` :
[image: Controller]

I have log file Like this `logs\log.php` :

```
ERROR - 2018-09-17 06:51:03 --> Severity: Warning --> Illegal string offset 'Catatan' /var/www/html/minilos/application/views/minilos/form_akkk.php 483
ERROR - 2018-09-17 06:51:03 --> Severity: Warning --> Illegal string offset 'Catatan' /var/www/html/minilos/application/views/minilos/form_akkk.php 483
ERROR - 2018-09-17 06:51:03 --> Severity: Warning --> Illegal string offset 'Rekomendasi' /var/www/html/minilos/application/views/minilos/form_akkk.php 502
```

I have code like this to auto load div 5 second , I want to auto load content `views\ngoding\load.php`

why my code to auto load div cannot run , can you resolve my code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to refresh div content in the controller function in codeigniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52435638/how-to-refresh-div-content-in-the-controller-function-in-codeigniter)

Comment: can you explain what output are you getting when you trying to execute it ?

Comment: it will print the contents of the log file ,every 5 seconds if new data is entered, it will load and add to the top row

Comment: @DevoAvidiantoP I have implemented same.. check answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is some errors in your current code. I suggest you to follow below code to achieve Auto reload div.

1. I have changed `$("#content").load('data.php')` to `$("#content").load('AutoLoadDiv/getData')` in view.
2. I also added `getData()` in your controller to fetch the log.(your load.php code is now in this function).

**Controller**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class AutoLoadDiv extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('ngoding/AutoLoad');  
    }

    public function getData() {
        $err = file_get_contents("application\logs\log.php");
        echo preg_replace(array('/(^|\R)ERROR\s*-\s*/', '/(^|\R)(.*?)\s*-->\s*/'), array('$1', '$1$2 '), $err);
        echo "<br>";
        echo "Content akan load selama 5 detik";

        for ($i = 0; $i <=10; $i++) {
            echo $i. "<br/>";
        }
    }

}
```

**View : ngoding/AutoLoad**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
    $("#content").load('AutoLoadDiv/getData')
    }, 5000);
    });
</script>

<style>
#content{
    background-color: #00A1E0;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-top : 10px;
    color : #fff;
    min-height: 200px;
    }
    #content,h1 {
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>

<title>Auto Load Page in Div using Jquery</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Auto Load Page in Div</h1>
    <div id="content">Please wait....</div>
</body>
</html>
```